# How to assign array and find size of array in hive?

Tags: arrays, hadoop, syntax, hive

Suppose I am getting Input string as multiple parameters from user.

e.g

```
hive -f demo.txt -hiveconf Name="a,b,c,d"
```

I want to pass these values(Names) in WHERE clause, by splitting the string using SPLIT function.

i.e

```
set a=SPLIT('${hiveconf:Name}',',');
```

But the output of SPLIT is an array.

So my question is how can i assign array in WHERE clause?

e.g.

```
WHERE Name IN (${hiveconf:a}[0:?])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`array_contains`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions) UDF:

```
WHERE array_contains(SPLIT('${hiveconf:Name}',','),'someValue')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...I have tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this WHERE Name IN (select SPLIT('1,2,3',','))